# Are there any initial consonants/syllables in modern Chinese dialects which are incompatible with some tones?

Tags: tones, word

Are there any initial consonants/syllables in modern Chinese dialects which are incompatible with some tones?

Can certain tones occur only in certain syllables (that is, within open or close ones)?

I am referring mainly to 普通话 (or 華語), but any other dialect will do

Comment: Which Chinese dialect? And it may be better to add some examples.

Comment: Yes, but it entirely depends on the dialect!

Comment: I removed the "any dialect" requirement because this makes the question overly broad and practically unanswerable by one person.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 You have also deleted the reference to two dialects as well, which made the question no less broad and unanswerable by a.n.y. person. Besides, I don't suppose we have an excessive number of dialect speakers here.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of this sort of phenomenon:

> Syllables that begin with unaspirated stops b, d, g, or affricates j, zh, z, and end in a nasal n or ng, as a rule don’t have second-tone forms.

Here's a [more extensive explanation of how this came about](http://pinyin.info/news/2011/the-where-and-why-of-missing-second-tones/)

Comment: Are there more like this?

Comment: Most chinese dialects have a different set of tones for "checked" or "closed" syllables. E.g., in [Cantonese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese_phonology#Tones), tones 7, 8, and 9 only exist in syllables ending in -p, -t, and -k.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete: While Cantonese checked-tone syllables can be numbered separately (7/8/9) for historical reasons, in practice, they are pronounced the same as tones 1/3/6, respectively. In addition, due to 變音, they may even be pronounced in tone 2.

Comment: @Claw So they are! Thanks for the info. Anyhow, it's easy to find other examples: In Shanghainese, all of the tones in words with a voiced initial are lower than (although the same "shape" as) the corresponding tones in words with unvoiced initials.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete: I suppose your Cantonese example isn't completely inapplicable. While the checked-tone syllables can be analyzed as having tones 1, 3, and 6, and can sometimes occur with 2, tones 4 and 5 are still disallowed; so you could say that Cantonese syllables ending in -p, -t, and -k never occur with tones 4 and 5.

Comment: @Claw Thanks for fixing my example. Checked tones really work as a pretty broad class of these. Since middle chinese had 8 tone categories (阴平,阳平,阴上,阳上,阴去,阳去,阴入,阳入) and only 2 of them were "checked" (the two 入 categories), the checked tones will be in complementary distribution with _something_. Of course it depends on how the particular language's tone categories (and syllable structure--e.g., Mandarin has no -p,-t,-k syllables) have changed over time.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your question is:

When two characters have similar tones, like a third tone followed by a third tone, such as:

```
你好 Nǐ hǎo
```

Mandarin speakers tend to find it easier to say if they pronounce the first character as `second tone`, like:

```
Ní hǎo
```

Or two `fourth tones` will sound too harsh, like:

```
不对 Bùduì
```

The `fourth tone` on 不 will change to second tone for easier pronunciation.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think that of Stumpy Joe Pete is closer to the initial intention of it.

Comment: 不 and 一 were initially 入 tone syllables as 意大利 demonstrates fourth tone can follow fourth tone